# How to get real database of resized image?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using firebase resized image extension to resize my image to get different thumbs.The images get resized correctly. Anyway, I wrote this code to insert the original image in real database.

```
   func sendDataToFirebase(){

             let productID = self.ref.childByAutoId().key
              let product = [
              "imagesID" : productID,
              "originalImage" : self.imgURL as String
                ]

            self.ref.child("images").child(productID!).setValue(product)



           let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "The image has been saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
               let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

               alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
               self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

           }
```

And this to store the image

```
func storeImageInFirebase(){
           let storeageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

           let imageName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
           let imagesReference = storeageRef.child("images").child(imageName)
           let imageData = self.imgView.image!.pngData()
           let metaData = StorageMetadata()

           metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
           imagesReference.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData){ (metadate, error)
               in
               guard metadate != nil else{
                   print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                   return
               }
               imagesReference.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error)
                   in
                   if error != nil {
                       print("Faild to download url:", error!)
                       return
                   }else{
                       // do something with url
                       self.imgURL = (url?.absoluteString)!
                       self.sendDataToFirebase()
                       //print(self.imgURL)
                   }
               })
           }
       }
```

This is according to original image. **What I want is to know how can get and sent the resized image to real database?**

Comment: I'm not very experienced with firebase, but I think you could send the image to firebase, get it back and resize automatically. Is there any reason why you NEED to send the resized image to firebase?

Comment: I want to get the url of resized image, so I can fetch it whenever I want.

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure this out. I will update you soon.

Comment: Are you using the realtime database or the cloud firestore?

Comment: I am using realtime database @alexholstv

Comment: Ok, nice to know. Pretty sure you can use cloud functions for realtime-database. Not sure how the process is, but a cloud function actually has the functionality of resizing on upload

Comment: Now, one more thing. I really am not familiar with this. You'd have to make your fair share of research first. Also, if i were you, i'd just resize in my code. Because let's say you want to resize only images on one view controller. I'm not sure if the cloud function will affect everything.